# If $ab + c = 1993,$ what is $a + b + c?$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

$a, b$ and $c$ are three prime numbers and $c$ is a one-digit number. If $ab + c = 1993,$ what is $a + b + c?$

So just by guessing, I've determined that $c=2$, and $a=181, b=11$. But if someone could explain how to do it quicker, I'd really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Where is this problem from? Is it a contest problem, perhaps from the year $1993$?

Comment: im actually not really sure :/

Answer (score 5):

You can make cases

- $ab=1993-2=1991=11\cdot181$
- $ab=1993-3=1990=2\cdot5\cdot199$
- $ab=1993-5=1988=4\cdot7\cdot71$
- $ab=1993-7=1986=2\cdot3\cdot331$

Comment: thank you for the cases!

Answer (score 3):

You just have to try possibilities for $c$ until you find a remainder that is the product of two primes.  If you start from the bottom you don't have far to go to find the solution you did.  If you trust the problem setter you can stop there.

Comment: ohhh ok got it!

Answer (score 1):

There's no really quick way.  Of course a few cases eliminate themselves quickly, e.g.
$c=3$ because $1993-3 = 1990$ is divisible by both $2$ and $5$.

Comment: oh ok thank you!